# Android unfortunately application has stopped

Tags: android

I tried to run my new application, but the AVD emulator says "Unfortunately Cycle_Counter has stopped". Cycle_Counter is the name of my app, of course.
Does anybody know why it is doing this?
There are similar questions on here, and I read through quite a few of them in the last hour, but I can't get mine to work.

This is what my console says:

```
2014-05-05 02:21:46 - Cycle_Count] ------------------------------

[2014-05-05 02:21:46 - Cycle_Count] Android Launch!

[2014-05-05 02:21:46 - Cycle_Count] adb is running normally.

[2014-05-05 02:21:46 - Cycle_Count] Performing com.example.cycle_count.MainActivity activity launch

[2014-05-05 02:21:46 - Cycle_Count] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_for_Nexus_4'

[2014-05-05 02:21:46 - Cycle_Count] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_Nexus_4'

[2014-05-05 02:21:53 - Emulator] Warning: No DNS servers found

[2014-05-05 02:21:53 - Cycle_Count] New emulator found: emulator-5554

[2014-05-05 02:21:53 - Cycle_Count] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

[2014-05-05 02:23:25 - Cycle_Count] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'

[2014-05-05 02:23:25 - Cycle_Count] Uploading Cycle_Count.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

[2014-05-05 02:23:26 - Cycle_Count] Installing Cycle_Count.apk...

[2014-05-05 02:24:43 - Cycle_Count] Success!

[2014-05-05 02:24:43 - Cycle_Count] Starting activity com.example.cycle_count.MainActivity on device emulator-5554

[2014-05-05 02:24:47 - Cycle_Count] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.cycle_count/.MainActivity }
```

Is it because of the "Warning! no DNS server was found!" error? 
As always, any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the LogCat:

```
05-05 04:07:41.890: D/dalvikvm(810): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
05-05 04:07:43.670: W/ActivityThread(810): Application com.example.cycle_count is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
05-05 04:07:43.700: I/System.out(810): Sending WAIT chunk
05-05 04:07:46.480: I/dalvikvm(810): Debugger is active
05-05 04:07:46.570: I/System.out(810): Debugger has connected
05-05 04:07:46.570: I/System.out(810): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-05 04:07:46.780: I/System.out(810): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-05 04:07:46.980: I/System.out(810): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-05 04:07:47.180: I/System.out(810): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-05 04:07:47.390: I/System.out(810): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-05 04:07:47.590: I/System.out(810): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-05 04:07:47.800: I/System.out(810): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-05 04:07:48.000: I/System.out(810): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-05 04:07:48.200: I/System.out(810): waiting for debugger to settle...
05-05 04:07:48.400: I/System.out(810): debugger has settled (1334)
05-05 04:07:49.220: D/AndroidRuntime(810): Shutting down VM
05-05 04:07:49.220: W/dalvikvm(810): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2a23ba8)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810): Process: com.example.cycle_count, PID: 810
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.cycle_count/com.example.cycle_count.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.example.cycle_count.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
05-05 04:07:49.260: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  ... 11 more
05-05 04:07:54.530: I/Process(810): Sending signal. PID: 810 SIG: 9
```

Code from MainActivity.java:
    package com.example.cycle_count;

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Build;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;




public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            EditText days = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            DatePicker dateset = ((DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1));

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dateset.getDayOfMonth());
            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, dateset.getMonth());
            cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, dateset.getYear());
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, Integer.parseInt(days.getText().toString()));

            DatePicker resultDatePicker = ((DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker2));
            resultDatePicker.updateDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),  cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),  cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is yur 24th line in mainActivity??

Comment: post your xml file too...

Comment: i think u added ur edittext, calendar and all that in your fragment_main.xml...copy them into activity_main.xml

Comment: @DaniFC What is your line 29 ?

Comment: Lal, I fixed it now. I was using fragment_main.xml instead of activity_main. It works now. Thank you guys!